# Is there a way to Sanitize a number of variables at once?

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I am trying to sanitize 54 variables at once.

Currently I am doing them one by one like so

```
        if($vissuedate != '') {

            $vissuedate = filter_var($vissuedate, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

            if($vissuedate == ''){

                    $vvalidate++;

                        } 
                }
```

I have a whole bunch more and want to ask if there is a way to validate all of them in one go?

Comment: Maybe `array_keys()` is of help?

Comment: I was thinking the same, maybe to assign them all to an array and then attempt to validate from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put all the keys from `$_GET` in an array:

```
$get_array = array_keys($_GET);
```

Or, if you want to skip some, you could use your own array:

```
$get_array = array('name','adress','phone',...);
```

Then:

```
foreach($get_array as $v=>$key){
     //check if exists
     if(!isset($_GET[$key]){
          //do something
          }
     else{
         //do sanitizing here             }       
    }
}
```

Or even, if you want to do different kinds of sanitizing, you could use an array with number:

```
$get_array = array('name'=>1,'adress'=>1,'phone'=>2,...);


foreach($get_array as $v=>$key){
     //check if exists
     if(!isset($_GET[$key]){
          //do something
          }
     else{
         switch($v){
             case 1: 
               //do something here;
             break;
             case 2:
               //do something else
             break;
             }
         }       
    }
}
```

Comment: I found another way to do this. I created a whole bunch of functions and validated each inside the function that is necessary

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through your `$_GET` like this:

```
<?php
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if($_GET[$key] != '') {
       $vissuedate = filter_var($_GET[$key], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
       if($vissuedate == ''){
         $vvalidate++;
       } 
}
```

[Or as you says](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4796879/devin-gray) assign them all to an array and then attempt to validate from there